# need to do xml tag validation without using xsd

Tags: c#, xml

```
 <component>
        <Cfac>Default</Cfac>
        <fbompart>503951302</fbompart>
        <fbomrev>000</fbomrev>
        <fbomdesc>CHANNEL, EYEBOLT MOUNT</fbomdesc>
        <fbommeas>EA </fbommeas>
        <fbomsource>S</fbomsource>
        <fjobno>04402-0000</fjobno>
    </component>
<component>
        <Cfac>Default</Cfac>
        <fbompart>503951305</fbompart>
        <fbomrev>000</fbomrev>
        <fbomdesc>TUBE,RND, 3.5 OD X 0.12 WALL HREW</fbomdesc>
        <fbommeas>EA </fbommeas>
        <fjobno>04402-0000</fjobno> 
</component>
    <component>
        <Cfac>Default</Cfac>
        <fbompart>503951305</fbompart>
        <fbomrev>000</fbomrev>
        <fbomdesc>TUBE,RND, 3.5 OD X 0.12 WALL HREW</fbomdesc>
        <fbommeas>EA </fbommeas>
        <fbomsource>M</fbomsource>
        <fjobno>04402-0000</fjobno> 
</component>
```

Here, in second component `<fbomsource>` is missing I need to validate this otherwise this will give me ‘object reference not set to an instance of an object’ error. my code is below please help me.

```
XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
                string xmldoc = data.ToString();
                doc.LoadXml(xmldoc);
                XmlNodeList _fpartno = doc.GetElementsByTagName("component");
                System.Collections.ArrayList Itemslist = new System.Collections.ArrayList(_fpartno.Count);
                for (int i = 0; i < _fpartno.Count; ++i)
                {
                    string partno = doc.GetElementsByTagName("fbompart")[i].InnerText;
                    string revision = doc.GetElementsByTagName("fbomrev")[i].InnerText;
                    string facility = doc.GetElementsByTagName("Cfac")[i].InnerText;
                    string Source = doc.GetElementsByTagName("fbomsource")[i].InnerText; // Here I get error
int count = 0;
{
//here goes some sql query and retuns zero or one
}

}
```

Thanks,
Pradeep

Answer (score -1):

If you don't have a DTD or XSD, nothing is missing and your XML is correct if its wellformed.

You have to check the XML within your code. Make two for-loops, one checking for not null, one wich actually does the work.
Something like

```
XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
string xmldoc = data.ToString();
doc.LoadXml(xmldoc);
XmlNodeList _fpartno = doc.GetElementsByTagName("component");
System.Collections.ArrayList Itemslist = new System.Collections.ArrayList(_fpartno.Count);
for (int i = 0; i < _fpartno.Count; ++i){
    if( doc.GetElementsByTagName("fbomsource")[i] == null){ 
        //this is an error in the XML, throw an Exception or or log it
    }
    // more validation if needed
} 
for (int i = 0; i < _fpartno.Count; ++i){
    // actual Code
}
```

I like to ensure, that the complete XML is valid and all needed values are present. (If there is no need, that all `component` need to be valid, you can us another appoach. In your sample-code there is some kind of NullPointer, because you call the method `InnerTex` of a null-reference.

Comment: this will not work in order, it only checks at the end not in the middle.

Comment: could you please provide the sample code, that you were talking using two for loop.

Comment: The code is correct. You could also simply add a nullcheck into your code doc.GetElementsByTagName("fbomsource")[i] == null ? "" : doc.GetElementsByTagName("fbomsource")[i]